# Generating numbers in order In field input / form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i was just wondering is there anyway i can generating numbers in order in field input / form i know you can do it random but i would like the numbers to load in order is there anyway to do this ?

```js
 function randomNumber(len) {
    var randomNumber;
    var n = '';

    for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        n += randomNumber.toString();
    }
    return n;
}

document.getElementById("userID").value = randomNumber(6)
```

```html
<form class="short_form" name="add" method="post" action="submit.php">

  <input type="text" name="x" value="" id="userID"> 
  
  <a href="#" class="sh_sub" nclick="document.add.submit();">submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by order of input?

Comment: instead of the numbers loading random in the field input / form i would like to load them in order

Answer (score 1):

Create an array, sort it, join the result and put it in the input field:

```js
const numbers = n => Array.from({length: n}).map( v => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) );
const fillNumbers = () => 
    document.querySelector("#numbers").value = numbers(6).sort().join("");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", fillNumbers);
```

```html
your numbers: <input disabled type="text" id="numbers"> <button>fill</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're finding the solution that makes numbers in input in order.

I use the method `Array.sort` and `Array.join()` to get the sorted numbers(in character).

And then return the value converted into integer.

If this is wrong, please tell me.

```js
function randomNumber(len) {
    var randomNumber;
    var arr = [];

    for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        arr.push(randomNumber.toString());
    }
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
      // descending
      return b-a;
      //or accending
      //return a-b;
    });
    return parseInt(arr.join(''));
}

document.getElementById("userID").value = randomNumber(6)
```

```html
<form class="short_form" name="add" method="post" action="submit.php">

  <input type="text" name="x" value="" id="userID"> 
  
  <a href="#" class="sh_sub" nclick="document.add.submit();">submit</a>
</form>
```